# Car as business expense, but not because of driving

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs

I was brainstorming a not-documented way of possibly deducting a car and associated costs as a business expense. But not because of normal driving. So I would like some insight into it.

I would like to use a car to house a small computer that is doing computations for a potentially profitable business venture.

Do the costs of the car now magically become tax deductible? Computers have only recently become small enough and low powered enough to consider something like this, and the car is merely property like any other property.

Comment: Definitely not.. For that matter you may have to work a bit harder than you expect to show that the computer is used 100% for business. Not to mention that you'd be absolutely begging for an audit.

Comment: @keshlam the point is to do things that would pass an audit, not be scared of them. The computer would be used 100% for business, what is hard about that? Get a $25 raspberry pi taped to the ceiling of the trunk running it's calculations and periodically broadcasting via long range communications. So now that's out the way, how does that change your answer?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the car?  If it could still do its job on a server rack connected to the Internet, the car isn't really necessary.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment: (1) PC hardware is historically harder to get approved as a business expense than many other kinds of business equipment, because so many people tried to claim gaming machines were deductable because they occasionaly ran business software. That's begging for etra attention. (2) As @NateEldredge says below, there's certainly near zero chance that you can claim the car is a Necessary Business Expense if you're using it as, essentially, a garden shed -- unlesx you can show that you ned a garden shed for the business and that the car was a cheap way to ger one.

Comment: Basically, if you can use the word "magically", you can assume it's been tried and ruled against. And while an audit is nothing to be afraid of if you aren't pushing the boundaries, this is one you can't hope they won't notice or will give you the benefit of the doubt on. If it violates the common sense test, you can bet dollars to donuts you can't get away with it.

Comment: @keshlam its not about "getting away with it", it is about coming to a rationalization based on the way the rules are written or the inefficiencies thereof. Many deductions are magically usable solely because the tax filer said they pursued a venture that is intended to be profitable. The additional steps that make that more defensible (incorporation, business bank account) are neither required by statute or necessary at all

Comment: Aside from anything else, what do you hope to gain by doing this?  If you buy a car for $X, use it for nothing but this scheme, and then deduct the $X, you haven't really saved any money; you bought the car tax-free but you're not getting any use out of it other than to run this computer setup that you only created as an excuse to the buy the car in the first place.  Even if you were able to deduct the car as an expense in this situation, you can't start driving it around for personal reasons, because then you definitely can't deduct (all of) if.

Comment: Are you using the car for anything other than housing this computer - Oh, I don't know, perhaps for actual driving? If so, no - the costs of the car do not now magically become tax deductible. And if not - what the heck are the "costs" of the car in that case?

Answer (score 4):

> To be deductible, a business expense must be both ordinary and necessary. An ordinary expense is one that is common and accepted in your trade or business. A necessary expense is one that is helpful and appropriate for your trade or business. An expense does not have to be indispensable to be considered necessary.  (IRS, [*Deducting Business Expenses*](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Deducting-Business-Expenses))

It seems to me you'd have a hard time convincing an auditor that this is the case.  Since business don't commonly own cars for the sole purpose of housing $25 computers, you'd have trouble with the "ordinary" test.  And since there are lots of other ways to house a computer other than a car, "necessary" seems problematic also.

Comment: Where do you find $25 computers ?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Raspberry Pi,  old junker laptop, ... The thought experiment didn't specify a _good_ computer, just one that would Do Something that might be a valid business task.

Comment: lets continue the thought exercise, what if the computer relied on the car's battery, and the car's metal frame to amplify signal.

Comment: The metal frame will not "amplify signal", nor (again) would you need a car if it did. You might be able to justify a directional antenna if you can explain why you can't relocate the computer, but a cantenna can be built for $10. Ditto the battery; even if you had a reason to run it off a car battery, that at most makes the battery a business expense and that only to the extent that the battery is used for nothing else. Really, trying to guess your way to where you wish a deduction existed just doesn't work. Try starting from the tax codes and working outward, if you must.

Comment: @keshlam yes sure, I've done a cantenna before. But now we have a cumbersome device much larger than the tiny computer, a device I don't want in my house, but want in my other property, in this example. Why the aversion to deducting the car vs the cost of a shed in the backyard? I would like to know how this distinction is applied within the tax code as we "work outward"

Comment: Aversion because I don't think you stand a snowball's chance in hell of convincing them that this will be the sole use if the vehicle, which is what you're trying to claim. If you think you can get away with it, I'm not going to try to stop you. But ___you asked if it would work___, and you've gotten an answer.

Comment: A non functioning junker case would do everything you need for $200. You would not convince the taxman to let you deduct a $10000 car and expenses to run it.

Comment: I'd think the only possible way you could do this is if you actually developed an income-producing product based on the car/computer combo.

Comment: @keshlam I didn't claim it would be the sole use of the vehicle. Would that be a prerequisite because I'm not aware that was.

Comment: @jamesqf sure, I may need a car for one job, and I need a cloud server for another project. Instead of dealing with the cloud server, for this purpose, I can have a raspberry-pi in the car doing hosting over cellular. It doesn't need the most reliable traffic or throughput, and can be woken up by pings. An easy example is that It could be an autonomous escrow server for blockchain transactions, and take 1% from the amount escrowed. Almost too easy, but IRS guidance is stuck in last century, so I have to brainstorm

Comment: If it has mixed uses, you can only deduct the percentage used by the business. If allowed at all, that would be negligable in your case. Again, ___read the tax code___ rather than guessing; there are clean analogies for this case wrt personal use of business vehicles, what can be legitimately claimed as a home office (probably closer), and the like. There is no magic here; there are clear rules. The century has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @keshlam the purpose of this discussion is to get references from said tax code. its a large body of text and derivative guidance, after all. The percentage used by the business would be substantial because it would be 24/7.

Comment: @CQM: But the fact that your Raspberry Pi is doing hosting is irrevelant to the fact that it's located in the car.  It would do the job as well (if not better) if left at home.  Your product would (at least as far as I understand IRS rules) have to depend on the car, so something like an improved OBDII code reader...